# python Crash course- html templates not rendering as text

Tags: html, django-templates

I am working on a project called learning logs in the book python crash course that should be 2nd edition, chapter 18. My IDE is pycharm.
I have created a template I call index.html that inherits from a base template called base.html. Running index.html on any browser just displays the code exactly as it is and not the what the output should be. It doesn't seem to be an IDE related problem, I used the exact same code using sublime text and notepad. What am I not doing right.

base.html

```
<p>
➊ <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
</p>
➋ {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

index.html

```
➊ {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
➋ {% block content %}
<p>Learning Log helps you keep track of your learning, for any topic
you're
learning about.</p>
➌ {% endblock content %}
```

tried using different IDEs, copy pasting the code from the book.

Comment: Are base.html and index.html on the same root directory?

Comment: Are you opening the file `index.html` directly in a browser window? That is a template file, and it isn't meant to be viewed directly. You should be visiting a URL defined in urls.py, such as `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: @japhyr. that was exactly the solution. Using the url instead of opening directly from the  IDE. Thanks alot

Comment: @HanKBeatz. Yes, same directory. japhyr gives me solution already. Thanks anyway.